# What criteria should apply a program to find duplicate matches

Tags: java, duplicates

I m basically new in programming and I want to do a program that finds duplicate files in a folder ( there are plenty of programs some of them free , don`t care , i want to do MY program ) and the question is what proprieties need 2 files to be a match ?
     At first i am thinking if they are mp3, to do a name and size check ,  a pdf the same , a txt the same + actual content checking ?
     And also in this order , i read somewhere that first they were checking the size and after that other stuff , and it does not feel right to me this way.
     I need some other or better ideas.

Thank you

Comment: Look into comparing the MD5 checksum of 2 files.

Comment: You are the "client" for this development project, so you get to decide what the criteria should be.  Start by asking yourself what >>you<< want "duplicate" to mean in this context.  If you can't tell us that, then we can't start to advise you.

Comment: thanks guy  ... still in with some problems , i read somewhere if the equals()  is true then also the hash-code is true but the other way around si not necessary to be true .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that's your idea to check extensions, and file sizes is kind of good. Depending on what you need i can prompt you something that i think would work:

**1. Check extensions:**

When you want to exclude some of them. But if you want to check exacly what is inside it will not work.

Simple example:

My_file.pdf having inside 0001 bits, and My_file.jpg having inside 0001 bits, will be excluded but still they are the same.

**2. Check size:**

If you will check extensions, checking file sizes is not very good idea couse having two files ".pdf" that contains (0001) and 2nd (0100) you can easly see that they are not equals, but checking size will return true, but ofcourse if two files are not equal size you can get rid of them and say they are not equals.

**3. Check Hash:**

Make hash from your files, and compare them will give you information if they are equals, couse hash functions will return always the same hash for the same objects.

Check more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function

**4. Check byte per byte:**

While it's not very good idea, but assuming that you have got 2x4GB files, you hash function can work very long, of course byte per byte will work longer but you can have got such a situation:

File1.pdf (4GB) Beggining of file: 011010...0     File2.pdf (4GB) 111010...0

As you can see, first check of first byte will automaticly return that those files are not equals, and you will save a lot of time.

Of course you must think, what you need, how you want to compare your files, those are just snipets which can help you in building your app.

All those methods are simple in Java, and you will not have got any problems with implement them.

PS: Sry for my english, it's not my primary language.

Comment: 1 - as I saw java is returning the whole name ( i mean also the extension ) so you will not have the problem "MyPic.jpg" equal with "MyPic.png" cause they have different extension 2 -i`m not sure i understand , 2 size are equal or not ? i`m not sure what you mean in 2 comment , 3 - i will check i have no idea what is a hash , 4 - the ideea of the program is mainly for mp3 ( i thought ) now i want also for small files texts and pdf and  other extension commonly used ( i think it s harder for photos  )

Comment: @LES 
1. Yes, you can easly check extensions in java, but you can have got files with diffrent extensions, and same data inside, especialy when you making those files by your own.
2. I just said that  'size of file1 != size of file2', will make a job, couse they can't be equal, but information that 'size of file1 == size of file2' generaly tells you nothing.
3. You have got already implemented hash functions in Java (i dont know how works hashCode() from Object Class couse i always used custom hash functions but i think that it will do the job)

Comment: but good to know as programmer how hash functions work, couse they are commonly used.
4. It's not important what extensions you are using, check such a classes in Java like File, BufferedInputStream. But if you are using small files for your program Hash functions will be a lot better.